# How to find the file details from a folder using sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I want to get the file details like file date, size, etc... from a folder using SQL server. Please share me the suggestion of both using command shell and without using command shell.

Comment: What are you going to do after you have the file list? Maybe SSIS would be more suitable tool for you?

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 options (at least) for doing that.

1. You can use `xp_cmdshell` for interacting with File System. [CheckHere](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx)
2. You can create a CLR assembly and use it in the procedure. [CheckHere](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2302/extending-file-system-operations-in-sql-server-using-clr/)
3. Using [OLE Automation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/). Also [CheckHere](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-file-size-using-T-SQL-9a237dcc)

Please keep in mind that both of the approaches have their procs and cons. The 1st option is easy and you need `sysadmin` permissions to use it directly. The 2nd option give you more control and can be used with less permissions, but you need to put some effort code the CLR assembly.

Comment: Is there any options to get the details using stored procedure/functions in sql server.

Comment: @Gopi, There is additional option using OLE Automation procedures of SQL Server. Updated the post with links. I hope this helps.